# Breaking on a deadlock between multiple startup projects in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, deadlock

I have multiple startup projects in my client/server solution. The server is a Console app and the client is a WinForms app. The server/console is launched first in case that matters.

Now there is a deadlock caused by some synchronization client-side code that blocks the server. Thread synchronization is done using simple `lock` statements.

When the deadlock occurs, both apps freeze of course and hitting pause/break in VS only breaks the server app, not the client. There are two questions here:

- How could I choose which project to break out of multiple start up projects?
- If a `lock` statement is stuck in a deadlock, is there a way to find out which line of code has a current lock on that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best solution would be to debug your client and server in separate instances of visual studio and setting startup projects accordingly.

As for the second question, I normally set a guid and output on create and release of a lock. to see if this is happening.  If it is, I set breakpoints and debug and look at the stack to see where on the calls are coming from. You may be able to output System.Environment.StackTrace to a log to get this information, but I've ever attempted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 Visual studios. One starting the console, one starting the server

I Would check if you really need a lock statement.

What do you want to lock ?
Do you always need a exclusive lock ?

Or are there some operations which can happen in parallel and only some which are exclusive ?

In this case you could use the [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
This can reduce the risk of deadlocks.